# Why does the number of Work Request in Queue always remains zero in !threadpool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, windbg, sos

I never saw the Work Request in Queue from the output of !threadpool above 0, so may I know what's the exactly meaning, and also how to simulate (by C# code) to make it over zero?

```
0:000> !threadpool
CPU utilization: 8%
Worker Thread: Total: 371 Running: 2 Idle: 363 MaxLimit: 32767 MinLimit: 8
Work Request in Queue: 0
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 2
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread:Total: 2 Free: 2 MaxFree: 16 CurrentLimit: 2 MaxLimit: 1000 MinLimit: 8
```

I have tried with the [Fibunacci threadpool example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679040.aspx) and 1000 work items:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

public class Fibonacci
{
    public void ThreadPoolCallback(object threadContext)
    {
        FibOfN = Calculate(N);
        DoneEvent.Set();
    }

    public int Calculate(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1) return n;
        return Calculate(n - 1) + Calculate(n - 2);
    }

    public int N { get; set; }
    public int FibOfN { get; private set; }
    public ManualResetEvent DoneEvent { get; set; }
}

public class ThreadPoolExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const int numberOfTasks = 100;
        var doneEvents = new ManualResetEvent[numberOfTasks];
        var fibArray = new Fibonacci[numberOfTasks];

        Console.WriteLine("launching {0} tasks...", numberOfTasks);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
        {
            doneEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            fibArray[i] = new Fibonacci {N= 40, DoneEvent= doneEvents[i]};
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(fibArray[i].ThreadPoolCallback, i);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Now run .symfix; .reload; .loadby sos clr; !threadpool; !threadpool");
        Debugger.Break();

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);
        Console.WriteLine("All calculations are complete.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added an example for a way how you might have tried it. If you like it, leave it in the question. If this is not what matches your implementation, then roll back my edit in the edit history. If possible, please provide such examples right away so that we don't have to guess and we don't need to spend so much time figuring out what your situation is.

Comment: I follow up you steps ,however the "Work Request in Queue" still  0, below is the details:
 CPU utilization: 0%  <br/>
Worker Thread:Worker Thread: Total: 4 Total: 4 Running: 4 Running: 4   <br/>Idle: 0 Idle: 0 MaxLimit: 32767 MaxLimit: 32767 MinLimit: 4   <br/>MinLimit: 4  <br/>
Work Request in Queue: 0  <br/>
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 0
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread:Completion Port Thread:Total: 0Total: 0 Free: 0 Free: 0 MaxFree: 8 MaxFree: 8 CurrentLimit:  : 4

Comment: Yes, that's why I have added it to the question and not as an answer. I don't know the answer.

Comment: Got it, and thank you for you editing, it looks good.BTW, the source code for the  "Work Request in Queue" in the following URL with method DECLARE_API(ThreadPool) .....    https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/70cfa355947ed82f7de8a56cac3bd38571cebfa5/src/ToolBox/SOS/Strike/strike.cpp